# How to retrieve the spatial coordinates of the Massif Central?

Tags: r, coordinates, mapping, france

I am new to geostatistics so I am looking for a solution to recover data for the geographic area of the Massif Central. I can easily retrieve all departments when it is the entire departement but the Massif Central also contains portions of departments. As you can see on this map [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massif_central#/media/Fichier:Massif_central.svg).

Below the departments by region:

**Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes**
Allier (all)
Ardèche (portion)
Cantal (all)
Loire (all)
Haute-Loire (all)
Puy-de-Dôme (all)
Rhône (portion)

**Bourgogne-Franche-Comté**
Saône-et-Loire (portion)
Nièvre (portion)
Yonne (portion)
Côte-d'Or (portion)

**Nouvelle-Aquitaine**
Corrèze (all)
Creuse (all)
Haute-Vienne (all)

**Occitanie**
Aude (portion)
Aveyron (all)
Gard (portion)
Hérault (portion)
Lot (all)
Lozère (all)
Tarn (portion)
Tarn-et-Garonne (portion)

These are the portions of departments that I cannot retrieve. Do you have a solution to select these portions? Knowing that you want to keep a spatial format and manipulate the object in order for example to put a different color for the different departments (all or portion).

Below my R code

```
library(cartography)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(geosphere)
france_metro = getData('GADM', country='FRA', level=2)
france_metro_sub <- subset(france_metro,
                     NAME_2=="Allier" | 
                     NAME_2=="Haute-Loire" | 
                     NAME_2=="Ardèche" | 
                     NAME_2=="Cantal" | 
                     NAME_2=="Loire" | 
                     NAME_2=="Rhône" | 
                     NAME_2=="Puy-de-Dôme" | 
                     NAME_2=="Aveyron" | 
                     NAME_2=="Lot" | 
                     NAME_2=="Lozère" | 
                     NAME_2=="Creuse" | 
                     NAME_2=="Haute-Vienne" | 
                     NAME_2=="Corrèze")
plot(france_metro_sub)
```

Comment: Do you need an outline of the Massif Central in order to do this? Do you have this, beyond the image from Wikipedia? Is it well-defined anyway? Is it the area above a certain height? Or is it a legal entity defined administratively via some borders? The wikipedia map https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massif_Central is different to the one you linked to.

Comment: Once you've got that outline (like if you had a shapefile of the MC area) then its one operation with something like `st_intersection` to get the departments. If that's what you want anyway....

Comment: @Spacedman I think, it is a legal entity defined administratively via some borders. I think taht the borders are the same in the wikipedia map en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massif_Central. 

In fact, i don't how get the coordinates of the borders for the departements which are truncated. And how to code that with R ?

Comment: You either need a shapefile or other spatial data with the Massif Central boundary, or you need to draw the boundary yourself on a georeferenced image, or you need to georeference a map with the boundary on it and digitise that.

Comment: "Massif central" is a geographic region with a fuzzy definition... I do not think there is any 'official' boundary for it. The one shown in wikipedia is a possible schematic one. You could simply digitalise you own using a tool such as http://geojson.io/, save it as whatever format to be then loaded in R.

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks a lot for your reply. I don't have the spatial data with the Massif Central boundary and that is the problem. If I understand correctly, in my case the best solution is raw the boundary myself on a georeferenced image, or i need to georeference a map with the boundary on it and digitise that. Can you have some suggestions on how to do that ? because I have no idea how to code that.

Comment: @julien Thanks. So i have to do this almost by hand?

Comment: You could try mapedit: https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2017/01/30/mapedit_intro.html

Comment: @Spacedman ok thanks, i will try to find tuto to do that !

Comment: I've done this using the QGIS georeferencer and map editing functions. Want it? Its the two yellow areas in the  image you linked.

Comment: @Spacedman Oh thanks a lot. Absolutely, I could see how you do that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the QGIS Georeferencing tool you can load the image from Wikipedia and match key points on the image to points on the main QGIS map using something like OpenStreetMap as a background map reference. That gets you a georeferenced image on the map. Note how the legend is skewed because the projection used by the image is not Mercator:

[image]

Then use QGIS' editing tools to create a new GeoPackage, and add a new layer to that package, and then create a new multipolygon feature by roughly digitizing the required area. Save this Geopackage.

[image]

The GeoPackage and referenced raster are in this public Box link for a while:

https://app.box.com/s/jbb8lx575mkiuogqsyaawi2t3a155zo2

Both can be loaded into R for plotting and analysis. For more on Georeferencing images, consult the QGIS documentation.